# No such property: id for class: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I have upgraded My Spring security plugin from **spring-security-core:1.2.7.2** to **spring-security-core:2.0-RC2** and my application is using Grails 2.3.7.

After upgrade I changed the imports accordingly so all compilation error got fixed but after running my application when I tried to access it `http://localhost:8080/login/auth` I got exception like :
*Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: id for class: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User*

as auth.gsp is using custom tag lib and code is like
if(springSecurityService.principal!="anonymousUser")user = SecUser.get(**springSecurityService.principal.id**)

here it is saying **No such property: id for class: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User**

Not sure how to fix this problem ...

Answer (score 0):

Until i can see what you want is to retrieve current logged user id, there is a special helper that only get the user id **"loadCurrentUser()"**

i paste this code from [grails spring security core plugin in section loadCurrentUser()](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/helperClasses.html)

```
class SomeController {

  def springSecurityService

  def someAction() { 
    def user = springSecurityService.isLoggedIn() ? springSecurityService.loadCurrentUser() : null 
    if (user) {
      CreditCard card = CreditCard.findByIdAndUser(params.id as Long, user)
      … 
     }
    …
  }
}
```

i hope it is usefull